# Определение номера телефона

Tags: android, android-sdk

Здравствуйте!

Возникла потребность подставлять номер телефона в TextView.

Сейчас пытаюсь получить данную информацию следующим образом:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String lineNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

На Genymotion всё работает, на реальных устройствах нет.

Подскажите, уважаемые, как получать номер? тк. например Viber на этих же устройствах номер определяет как-то. Спасибо за помощь!

permisions пропасаны.

UPD. Требуется получение своего номера телефона, т.е. номера с сим-карты в устройстве.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
    ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (account.name.length() == 13 && account.name.substring(0, 4).equals(getString(R.string.phoneNumberPattern))) {
            phoneNumbers.add(account.name);
        }
    }
```

Где  в res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="phoneNumberPattern">+375</string>
```

В разрешениях нужно не забыть указать

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: правильно понял, что это получение списка номеров из контактов?

Comment: @dramf, нет,  `AccountManager` используется именно для извлечения имён учетных записей, которые пользователь хранит на устройстве, и с контактами никак не связан. `AccountManager` может хранить данные об учётных записях пользователя в Google+, Facebook и т.д., т.е., кроме телефона, с помощью него можно получить электронный адрес и другие данные.

Answer (score 1):

```
String main_data[] = {"data1", "is_primary", "data3", "data2", "data1", "is_primary", "photo_uri", "mimetype"};
    Object object = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, "data"),
            main_data, "mimetype=?",
            new String[]{"vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2"},
            "is_primary DESC");
    if (object != null) {
        do {
            if (!((Cursor) (object)).moveToNext())
                break;
            String s1 = ((Cursor) (object)).getString(4);
        } while (true);
        ((Cursor) (object)).close();
    }
```

**permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```